# The Right Distro for text-based needs

Tags: vim, package-management, zsh, distribution-choice

I'm searching for the right Linux Distro. My four current ideas are:

- Gentoo
- Grml
- Arch
- Debian

But I'm absoluty open to more alternatives. Now a little bit more about my needs:

- I want it to be really small by default, so I can customize the hell out of it.
- I want to use text-tools only, I don't need any graphics on that OS
- I'm going to use ZSH, Vim, the NEO Layout and maybe XMonad
- I want to have a really nice package manager
- The OS will mainly be used for programming

My CPU is an Intel Core 2 Duo, 64 Bit, of course.

My questions are now:

- Which package manager is the most advanced: APT, Portage or Pacman?
- Which distro fits my needs best?
- What is the easiest way to run it from an USB-Flashdrive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used Debian, Gentoo and Arch for a couple of years each. The more customizable by far is Gentoo. But it takes thought each time you want a given package. Debian is, well Debian: a mainstream distro, that can feel bloated to some. Given your requirements, I think you might like Arch. It's pretty lightweight and there are tons of bleeding-edge packages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Frederik! I think I will try Arch :)

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement 1 say:

> I want it to be really small by
>   default, so I can customize the hell
>   out of it.

Then, you DON'T want your package manager to be such advanced. Anyway AFAIK, portage is better for the "customization" thing, but maybe you want to [read more about it](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=2&chap=1) because I'd never used it.

APT is really cool, and I'm debian user, but I don't know how much simple do you want your system.

Pacman is really good, and I used Arch for a year. Arch's system simplicity and customization are pretty and it's BSD-like feeling is really different. The only thing about pacman is that it's not as intuitive as APT, but as workaround, you have this [Pacman Rosetta](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_Rosetta).

BTW: Maybe you want a Linux system, but if you don't care, you could try FreeBSD, it'ill be nice for you.

Cheers

Comment: Why would she want a FreeBSD?

Comment: What does size/customisability have to do with the package manager?

Comment: @Tshepang, is not about PM, but about the distro itself. The most customizable system is the system that you build by yourself. I know it's "possible" to reconfigure everything but, being realistic, if your package manager installs lots of "maybe you want it too" software, and writes lots of configuration, then your system gets harder to customize. If you install the very basic software in debian, you'ill still find lots of programs that you will never ever use, same but worst in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Tshepang, about FreeBSD: maybe she want FreeBSD because of the simplicity. Debian is a distro, that's an Operating System and a lot of configuration done for your needs. FreeBSD is just an Operating System, and you need to configure everything. It's harder to install and configure, but it runs fast and it's fully customizable. You need to set up the daemons, network configuration, etc.. and I found it better to text-based needs than any Linux distro. You compile your programs from ports, and install binary packages if needed.

Comment: Does FreeBSD run faster than Debian in your experience? Are you here referring to the default install, or would did you compare with a similar assortment of packages installed?

Comment: Regarding *lots of "maybe you want it too" software*, are you aware of the difference between Depends and Recommends?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of it, but some "_depends_" aren't depends. An stupid example: In debian, the package **git** depends on **curl** and **expat**, but you can compile git without them. It's an stupid case, since you'ill almost always use curl or expat with git but... maybe you just want a little testing environment with versioning, and you just have FTP access, then you don't need them. In this case, stupid or not, the package manager has additional depends that you don't need.

Comment: And regarding FreeBSD yes... in my experience it runs hell of fast with similar software installed. Minimal text-based installations are different too. You need 150Mb free disk space for the minimal FreeBSD system, and 250Mb for the minimal Debian. And I still think FreeBSD has a best terminal interface (using mouse on it by default)

Comment: What is it about an advanced package manager that reduces system flexibility? What are examples of advanced package managers? Examples of primitive ones?

Comment: D4RIO, Tshepang: Thanks for your discussion. Gave me some insight. Thought about BSD, too. But I want the Linux kernel, because I had a lecture about it and want to digg further into it.

Comment: @Tshepang, I took a second to think and it's mostly because of the packages and distro itself. Not the PM. Anyway, the easy way to install software in Debian/SuSE/Arch implies using the PM with it's repos and depends.

Comment: @D4RIO: I'm still curious what you meant by advanced vs. not-advanced package managers. Examples?

Comment: @D4RIO: What's nice about FreeBSD terminal interface? I haven't used it, so I'm wondering what I'm missing.

Comment: advanced PM:  it will try to think for you
not-advanced: maybe ports

FreeBSD terminal interface: No technicall "wow" differences, but better manual pages, better documentation overall, standard traditional UNIX console with nice features, very lightweight. The whole system makes me feel better. I feel Linux consoles are mixes of different text-based software, mostly working fine, when FBSD is one organized system with the same philosophy everywhere.
Install FreeBSD and test it, you'ill note the difference after a while.

Comment: Anyway, maybe it's subjective as every OS comparison: It's like comparing Ferraris and Porsches. Different styling, handling and brand image but they're both high-performance sports cars. Every user has it's own reasons.